# Community Wiki Reboot

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

If your were to redesign the SO platform, and part of your design spec was to abandon the community wiki concept, what would you do?

In particular:

1. Users should not have a community wiki checkbox.
2. After 8/9 edits a post should not flick to community wiki.

Can you think of any other ways that you could achieve the same goals CW tries to solve that would be built on a simpler set of concepts.

Comment: I'd just end up recreating Community Wiki...

Comment: This should be made into a community wiki...haha!

Comment: I'd change its name.

Comment: Could you please include a link to what those goals are?

Comment: @Neil, Then the answers will become community wiki, which in turn discourages quality answers .... Change the name if you see fit, rephrase it, I don't care if this becomes community wiki.

Comment: @Rob, nobody, not even the most seasoned users of SO fully understand community wiki. There are 171 questions tagged CW on meta that shed some light on the goals.

Comment: @Rob @waffles no one knows what CW really means because half the people think it means one thing and the other half think it means another.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I've been away for a while and thought maybe the purpose of CW had finally been stated authoritatively somewhere in the meantime. I guess it still hasn't. So what good is a discussion about how to re-implement certain goals when nobody knows what those goals are? First work out what you want to accomplish. *Then* ask how to do it.

Comment: Are you working on an SO clone and want to make it better, @waffles?

Comment: The original purpose was simply to make collaboration more widely available and to actively invite the same. That's simple. The use as a safe(ish) harbor for "soft" or marginal context arose from the subjective wars to end all subjective wars. That's a norm, and as such is not easy to nail down.

Comment: @Ladybug, well its not exactly a clone and I don't seem to need CW anyway due to the way I designed it and the tighter scope of the community.

Comment: The main change I would make to CW is that answers would not be CW just because the question is.

Comment: _Is_ CW going to remain alive, now that low-rep users can (sort of) edit? The only problem I see with trashing it entirely is that a bunch of old-timers will get sudden rep spikes when their two-year-old poll posts suddenly count.

Comment: @Pop There's also still the difference that CW allows it without freezing things and without needing approval. To an extent, that's actually significant.

Answer (score 9):

I would drop it entirely.

The biggest advantage is that it allows low-rep users to edit stuff. I think that should be allowed anyway, with edits by low-rep users held for approval by higher-rep users.

The other common use for CW is in removing discussion/list questions from the rep system. These questions don't really belong on S[OFU] anyway, but folks like them - so move them into a separate "lounge" forum and be done with it.

Comment: Just because a topic calls for collaborative answering, doesn't mean that low-rep users are very likely to make desirable edits to them. So I'm with @Shog9(of).

Comment: A lot of what you have said in the past turns, at least to some partial degree, as status-completed, doesn't it? Questions can no longer be marked CW by their authors, and now low rep users can edit but require approval by higher reps...

Comment: What Grace said. Have a belated upvote.

Comment: @Grace: yeah, I am exceedingly happy about the editing thing. Honestly never thought it would happen. Much more elegant than CW ever was, IMHO.

Comment: @shog9 I was happy too until I saw the insane amount of turd-polishing that goes on with suggested edits.. "I took this terrible unreadable question and corrected 1 spelling mistake for the benefit of humanity, enjoy!"

Comment: @Jeff: I suspect we [the community in general, me in particular] will have to get a lot more comfortable clicking that "reject" button in cases where *the final result* isn't up to snuff. Mmmm, delicious novelty...

Answer (score 7):

Number of edits shouldn't determine community wiki status.

Code is iterative, and when I improve code I've referenced here I usually update my answers.

With enough time the usage of SO will transform from a Q/A system to a knowledge base.  Eventual knowledge base status should be taken into consideration - and because of this eventuality I shouldn't be less likely to garner rep simply because I polish my answers!

Answer (score 1):

> Users should not have a community wiki checkbox.

Is this an issue somehow? Is it too much of a proxy for casual discussion? Because if it is, not allowing community wiki is not an option. You need to direct that flow of discussions *elsewhere*. I'm sure there are genuine cases of community wikis that are relevant discussions, and that people should feel able to start a relevant discussion in an "off the books" sort of way.

> After 8/9 edits a post should not flick to community wiki.

I never agreed with that rule personally.

In the end, I'm not voting you either up or down, I'm split right down the middle. First question remains, though: how is this an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm....

Well, you could do a "discussion" type post that does not accumulate rep or work toward badges. It, too, would be a check box, but it would not allow arbitrary edits of any post like CW does.

Comment: Yeah, and it would automatically close itself, saving me the trouble. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Neil Butterworth's comment: I'd change its name.

I think that a lot of new users are confused as to what Community Wiki means and what it does, and the name doesn't really convey it. I mean it makes perfect sense to me now but I've been using the site for over a year.