# 10k+ users can see flags now, but can't unflag

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, flag-queue

The new flag queue for 10k+ users is very interesting, but it lacks a crucial feature: Actually *disagreeing* with the flags shown.

Those who think a contribution deserves a flag, will add their own flag or close vote to the pile. Those who think the flag is *unjustified*, can do nothing except maybe upvote the contribution - which may not be at all what they really want to do.

Also, if I understand it correctly, questions disappear from the queue once they have been closed, so there is no way to review the 10k+ community's recent decisions.

As it stands, I don't think this is going to do good - it'll help a lot in the case of genuine crap of course, but it'll massively increase the number of unjustly closed contributions because it sends a huge mob (i.e. us) towards everything that got flagged.

Am I overlooking some hidden wisdom? How is this feature supposed to work?

Comment: Invalid flags will be dismissed by a moderator in due course.

Comment: @Robert but what if 5 people vote something "too localized"? That won't necessarily come to a moderator's attention at all, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering what to do with the flags queue. (Of course, I had no idea it's a new feature either since I just got my almighty privileges)

Comment: @Pekka: That seems consistent with the voting pattern now; you can't vote to reopen until the post is closed.

Comment: @Robert yeah, but in the context of a queue that quickly shows you a list of questions outside your usual tags, that becomes a huge flaw. One should be able to contravene a flag here

Comment: I've seen that problem with piled on spam flags, but I'm not sure there's much you can do about it. Conntravening a close flag during the closing process would change the whole closing dynamic. I'm not sure a question's tags (or a closer's expertise in those tags) has much to do with it; a bad question is a bad question, regardless of its tags.

Comment: +1 if you can dogpile on the rabbit, you should at least be able to claim it is duck season.

Comment: @Robert, I've made _comments_ on questions and answers that garnered two or three spam flags but I thought were legitimate, if ham-fisted, posts. Sometimes they even survived long enough for the spam flags to expire or be removed by moderators... :)

Comment: @sarnold: Yes, that is what should happen.  I have noticed that there are some spam flags in the mod queue that are now also accompanied by "invalid flag" flags.  Those flags are really useful; we'll see in time how that fleshes out.

Comment: [Invalid comment after reading further -- how can I delete it? ] I also just saw a post that was flagged (automatically?) as low quality. Looking at the post itself I think one part of it could be shortened, but in total the post was good. Still I can't just disagree with the "low quality" flag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The new flag queue for 10k+ users is very interesting, but it lacks a crucial feature: Actually disagreeing with the flags shown.

No, it doesn't:

> [image]
>
> **It has invalid flags**
>   I do not agree with the existing flags on this answer, they are incorrect and should be ignored.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't aware of that. Nice!

Comment: Oh wow, I totally missed that.  I had just been ignoring the invalid flags.

Comment: But I will never expect "unflag" to be in the list of types of flags!   (yes I not "stop" is on the "start" menu in windows...)

Comment: @Ian true, but it arguably is something one comes across sooner or later.

Comment: OK, but this is buried in a list where you don't expect it. Any chance of pulling it out to be it's own bullet item?

Comment: I agree. The only reason I would say don't bother pulling it out is because the only people who go into this queue in the first place are motivated to find how to do it properly, and will eventually stumble on this post.

Answer (score 9):

As noted in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94133/how-and-when-should-we-use-the-invalid-flag-flag), there's an "Invalid flag" option. It's specifically above the "other" flag option when you choose to flag it. Use it to indicate disagreement. Or, use the "other" flag to indicate that the action is wrong.

Remember, flags don't directly cause any effect. They only serve as an indicator to moderators about what should be done, such as in case the community members cannot directly intervene (i.e. deletions, or sub-3k closures). So to that end, you can influence the resolution against what others have flagged if you can provide substantial points in your own flag to explain why that flag is invalid.

Note that as mentioned in the post I linked, flag weight is... oddly handled at the moment. But disregarding the effects on flag weight itself, there is well enough ability to disagree with the provided flags.

If you're concerned about the actual community actions taken from it (such as accumulated close votes) prior to any moderator intervention, it's no different than how it is with the `close` tab on the 10k tools. You have all the same faculties to oppose those closures as you do with any closure actions suggested by the flags. Stand by and wait for reopen, voice your reason in comments, and similar other options all work to indicate disagreement.

Comment: ah-ha! So there is more to the queue than I thought. It keeps disappearing so quickly :) I'll look into this the next time the queue comes up again, thanks.

Comment: So, in the end, is it worth adding our own flag if we agree with it or we should do it only if we disagree?

Comment: @Aleadam If you agree with it and you think it's urgent, then piling on flags helps indicate the severity of the issue. It also helps in those kinds of toss-up situations where the moderators can't really be sure and one voice alone isn't enough to make a wise decision.

Comment: I was thinking about the "not an answer" flags. They're usually not urgent, but I can see that 3-4 flags can make the decision easier and faster for the mods. I don't know how the flags are shown to mods, so I don't want to spam anyone either.

Comment: piling on flags is good ... its your way of agreeing or disagreeing with a flag