# Flag or disagree won't let me disagree

Tags: support, flags, 10k-tools, declined-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [10k+ users can see flags now, but can't unflag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94186/10k-users-can-see-flags-now-but-cant-unflag)

In the 10k tools, in the flags tab, when it shows a flagged post it has a button like so:

[image]

yet, when I press that button, it only brings up a flagging dialog, there is no way I see to disagree.  Please let me disagree.

Comment: I considered voting this as a duplicate, but I personally felt that there's a bit of difference between "I can't disagree with a flag" (pre-UI-change that added the word disagree) and "I can't disagree with a flag when it says I can" (post-UI-change).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm just going to steal Jeff's image from an answer elsewhere. When you click `flag or disagree...`, you'll get the following dialogue, which the relevant section has been highlighted.

[image: flag as invalid]

It's [already been stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94186/10k-users-can-see-flags-now-but-cant-unflag/94319#94319) that it's not the most intuitive way to go about it, but it's certainly present.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed it, and that I had to post this comment twice for it to stick.