# Flag Declined although suggested action was followed

Tags: discussion, flags, merged-questions, declined-flags

I flagged [Hide TD into DIV Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099777/hide-td-into-div-using-jquery) as a duplicate of [Hide TD into DIV Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114138/hide-td-into-div-using-jquery) which are exact duplicates. I voted to close it as an exact duplicate and also flagged it and mentioned in the comment that it might be a good idea to merge the two (*as both had comments/answers*), if possible, to a single Question.

The flag was declined with ***declined - The other post was closed and the answers merged with this one***

Is that a valid decline reason ? (*the fact that the merge was not done from Question-1 to Question-2 but instead from Question-2 to Question-1*)

I am just asking for clarificaion reasons. (*not hurt or anything..*)

Comment: I was tempted to close as a duplicate of, *for example*, [Flag marked invalid even though question was closed for same reason: can I challenge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98347/flag-marked-invalid-even-though-question-was-closed-for-same-reason-can-i-chall), but the text of the decline reason is intriguing indeed...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was my doing, it was not an unintentional dismissal of the flag.  I had performed all of the actions outside of the browser window.

When I returned to the browser window with the mod queue, it was refreshed, and I lost track of the fact that it was you that submitted the flag in the first place by the time I saw the flag again.

I would have marked it as "helpful", but at that point, the merge had already been done, and I thought it was a flag from someone else, to which I wanted to convey the message that it had already been done.

Unfortunately, the *only* way to send a message is to decline.

It was a mistake on my part, and I apologize that it conveyed the wrong message, and impacted your flag weight.

Comment: no worries.. just wanted to make sure if there is a ***correct/proper order*** to flag in such cases..

Comment: @Gaby: There absolutely is, and you did the right thing.  I assure you that if you flag things correctly (as you did here), this impact on your flag weight will be insignificant. =)

Comment: If someone flags something I've just dealt with I usually give then the benefit of the doubt - i.e. assume that they had the page open before I closed/deleted so had no way of knowing that it had already been dealt with. Obviously if it's been closed for a while that's a different matter.

Comment: So what did we learn from this? Mods want to be able to respond to flags, even if they are helpful, because they are often open for improvement.

Comment: LOOOOL!  Oh, I so love not *always* being the one.  Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't: I don't know what exactly what you mean by "the one", but it appears I might be that person regardless haha.

Comment: @casperOne: "WHY DID SOME DUMB MOD SCREW UP" "uh, I'm the one that..." "WHY WAS MY FLAG XYZ" "I was the one that" "WHO WILL RID ME OF THIS TURBULENT MOD?" "I'm the one who is turbulent and..."

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't: Oh yeah, I'm *definitely that guy* now.

Answer (score 3):

That does not sound like a valid reason at all, regardless of 1-2 or 2-1 your advice was correct and has in the end been taken. kudos

Comment: thanks for the input. That is what i thought too..

Answer (score 3):

Don't sweat it, it sounds like your flag was valid and a (possibly new) moderator just didn't know the proper procedure. We'll make sure to mention it to them so they don't make the same mistake.

Yes it cost you a little flag weight, but don't worry one correct call and you recover that, and the flag weight doesn't actually count for much anyway. Trust that your input and good community participation are appreciated. Thanks for not taking the mistake personally, that makes life a lot easier for moderators!

Comment: Thanks @caleb. No problem with the flag weight.. just wanted to get informed if there is a *proper order* to flag such cases..

Comment: @Gaby: Use your best judgement on the order (usually the newer one merged into the older but it could vary if the quality is better on one or the other), but either way to order goes the flag bringing the need for a merge to a moderators attention was valid.