# Flagged as not a real question is Invalid but it is closed as not a real question

Tags: support, flags, closed-questions, declined-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Flag deemed Invalid, but question closed for the same reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97572/flag-deemed-invalid-but-question-closed-for-the-same-reason)

[Mean, Median, Mode, Range - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121188/mean-median-mode-range-java) seemed not a real question to me, so I flagged it; my flag was marked invalid, but the question was still closed as not a question.

[image: screenshot]

Is this a bug, or how should I understand this?

Comment: This has been brought up like 20 times in the past 2 weeks on meta.  Please utilize the handy dandy search function in the top right (when you click it it **EMBIGGENS**!)

Comment: I was searching but the first 5 questions doesn't fit.

Comment: @JNK, maybe this points out a larger problem with the flagging system that should be addressed.

Comment: @lance I think you may be right, but more I think it's because people are overly concerned about flag weight and don't understand how it works.

Comment: /megaultrafacepalm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. The user who marked your flag as invalid is not one of the users who voted to close that question.
The moderator who marked your flag as invalid probably thought your flag was not correct. Consider also that, given the number of flags the moderators deal with, they could make some mistakes, in some cases; after all, they are human beings.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that

> This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete...

I disagree that it is

> rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

It had four close votes and two good answers when I looked at it.  Sure, it could have been more specific, but there was plenty of information there for people to answer the question.  Your first course of action should always be to use the tools you have available to deal with a problem.  That question could be improved through editing.

In short, that question **did not** require moderator attention.

Comment: `In short, that question **did not** require moderator attention.` should be a dismiss reason.