# Very Low Quality flag not shown for question at -1

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

This question does not offer me the vlq flag amongst the flags, even though it's at -1.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/8020284/131433

Could it be that it is hidden once someone else has used it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111114/what-happened-to-the-very-low-quality-flag-reason/111116#111116), and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110404/proposed-improvement-to-flagging-for-answers/110754#110754), the "Very low quality" flag only appears on questions once they are closed.

The flag is now available on the question you link.

<sub>BTW, the question was at `-1` when you posted your question, not `-4`.</sub>

Comment: I've been known to be confused, but I am sure I saw a lower number than -1.

Comment: Well, it had 4 close votes when I saw it because of your Q here, so I maybe that's where that number came from.

Comment: looks like that's what happened in my unawake brain.