# Moderators should have to give a reason for deleting questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

My question ["Modern" OpenGL on Linux with GLFW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776936/modern-opengl-on-linux-with-glfw) was deleted. I don't know the reason because there's no explanation for the deletion. I thought I was getting some useful information in the responses and I think I'm on the right track now, and was intending to post my own answer once I've confirmed something with some test code.

So please could it be compulsory for moderators to give a reason for deletion, so people asking bad questions have a chance to learn how to avoid similar mistakes in future.

Comment: Most of the time deleted questions deserve to be deleted and the close reason is usually more than enough, mod time has value in this community. In the cases that it's not 'obvious' - I think posting about your specific question here (like you did) is the right course of action and is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Coming to Meta to discuss deletion of a question = good. Suggesting, for what must be the thousandth time, that commenting be made compulsory for deletion because of that one instance where it may have been unjustified = bad.

Comment: @Pekka That wasn't my motivation for making the suggestion. I thought there probably would be a good explanation for the deletion, but as it was SO gave no clue as to what that reason was. Perhaps the problem isn't moderators failing to give a reason, but SO not showing enough information on deleted posts eg "This had been marked Very Low Quality".

Comment: @realh In your case, the VLQ flag was applied incorrectly, which is (I believe) very rare. I think in most cases (not yours) of Very Low Quality questions, the rule applies that if you need explaining *why* it was deleted, you're probably not able to contribute to the site.

Answer (score 17):

I deleted your question.  It had received a "Very Low Quality" flag.  I'm pretty strict about the Very Low Quality flag, [as I've explained before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189362/why-were-these-very-low-quality-flags-declined/189373#189373).

In this case, I read your post and couldn't figure out what the actual question you were trying to ask was.  Not only that, but I couldn't conceive of a way to edit it into an actual question.

That takes care of *the* two criteria of Very Low Quality:

1. Bad Post
2. Unsalvageable through editing

In this case, it seems like half of your post is a diatribe about OpenGL, and the other half is a conversation between you and yourself about what could work.

In short, it's very confusing and doesn't read like an actual question.

I'm happy to undelete it; but I recommend that you pare it down to the following:

1. Your actual problem.
2. A question about this actual problem.

In general when it comes to Very Low Quality flags, they are a shortcut to deletion. If something is flagged as VLQ, it's begging a moderator to delete it outside of the normal channel of closure -> community deletion.  If a post is flagged as "Very Low Quality", the flag message may as well be:

> This post doesn't deserve to go through the normal closure -> deletion process. It should be summarily removed from the site.

I could get behind a deletion message that says (if a post is deleted summarily by a moderator through the VLQ flag queue):

> This post was deleted by a moderator because it is [Very Low Quality](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). Please improve your post and then flag it for undeletion.

Of course, this would require a help center dedicated to VLQ and how to improve a post -- but you get the idea.

Comment: If it were me, I don't know that I even would have marked the Low Quality flag as helpful in this case. I know from past experience that the people who hang around the [opengl] and related tags are sticklers for question quality, so they tend to be a little harder on things that would be perfectly fine elsewhere. While the question is a little unclear (and maybe based on one or two incorrect assumptions), I think with an edit it could be made into a good, viable question. This question doesn't strike me as something that needs instant removal or closing (what the Low Quality flag is for).

Comment: @BradLarson That's completely fair.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't see any votes or markers about Very Low Quality. Would they have been visible before it got deleted? I've tried to improve my original question, but I didn't want to pare it down too much, otherwise some of the comments would lose context. I think Nicol Bolas' first comment leads to the right answer, but I want to confirm it with code before I post an answer.